# Can't show the image with white text, opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

The original image is

[image]

```
font                   = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
bottomLeftCornerOfText = (10,150)
fontScale              = 1
fontColor              = (255,255,255)

cv2.putText(img=img,text='Hello World!', 
    org = bottomLeftCornerOfText,
    fontFace=font, 
    fontScale=fontScale,
    color=fontColor,
    lineType=cv2.LINE_AA,
    thickness=1)
```

After running the code above, I got image like this

[image]

Only text showed and the background image disappeared. I also tried other colors like blue and green, they all worked fine, both image and text were kept. I wonder why white text doesn't work here and how can I fix it.

Comment: Works fine on my machine. I get to see white text on that image. I would suggest to show the full code. The way you are displaying or saving the image maybe wrong.

Comment: mathplotlib assigns a defaut colormap to grayscale images. You need to specify a grayscale colormap or use OpenCV to display your image.

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote all working answers, and accept the one you like the most. Probably you know this, but this is to let the community know which answers were useful and to reward the people for their time and effort as well ;) See this meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/ and meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the image type float from 0.0 to 1.0? Is it one channel grayscale? You are assigning text color with 3 channels and 255 valued... Probably you're having trouble because of one of those.